# Linking against library corrupts ELF program headers

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, ld

I am trying to link my C++ executable against a shared C library (also written by me / my colleagues).

The C++ executable just contains a main that prints "Hello World" to stdout and returns 0.

It runs fine. But as soon as I dynamic link against my C library (I am not even calling into this lib) my C++ executable fails at startup:

```
/opt/av-server # strace ./program 
execve("./program", ["./program"], [/* 10 vars */]) = 0
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=NULL} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
Segmentation fault
```

I did some research and found out that as soon as I link against the C library my ELF header starts looking very strange. The entry point address is suspiciously low and the addresses of the first LOAD are all zero:

### Corrupt Header

```
Elf file type is DYN (Shared object file)
Entry point 0x6d8
There are 6 program headers, starting at offset 52

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  EXIDX          0x000960 0x00000960 0x00000960 0x00010 0x00010 R   0x4
  LOAD           0x000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00974 0x00974 R E 0x10000
  LOAD           0x000ee0 0x00010ee0 0x00010ee0 0x0015c 0x00164 RW  0x10000
  DYNAMIC        0x000ef0 0x00010ef0 0x00010ef0 0x00110 0x00110 RW  0x4
  GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000 0x00000 RW  0x10
  GNU_RELRO      0x000ee0 0x00010ee0 0x00010ee0 0x00120 0x00120 R   0x1

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     .ARM.exidx 
   01     .hash .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .rel.dyn .rel.plt .init .plt .text .fini .rodata .ARM.extab .ARM.exidx .eh_frame 
   02     .init_array .fini_array .jcr .dynamic .got .data .bss 
   03     .dynamic 
   04     
   05     .init_array .fini_array .jcr .dynamic
```

I guess this explains why the program is segfaulting: It jumps to 0 :/ As comparison this is the header that is generated when I don't link against the lib:

### Good Header

```
Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x10588
There are 9 program headers, starting at offset 52

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  EXIDX          0x0007fc 0x000107fc 0x000107fc 0x00018 0x00018 R   0x4
  PHDR           0x000034 0x00010034 0x00010034 0x00120 0x00120 R E 0x4
  INTERP         0x000154 0x00010154 0x00010154 0x00013 0x00013 R   0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-linux.so.3]
  LOAD           0x000000 0x00010000 0x00010000 0x00818 0x00818 R E 0x10000
  LOAD           0x000ef0 0x00020ef0 0x00020ef0 0x00148 0x001dc RW  0x10000
  DYNAMIC        0x000f00 0x00020f00 0x00020f00 0x00100 0x00100 RW  0x4
  NOTE           0x000168 0x00010168 0x00010168 0x00020 0x00020 R   0x4
  GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000 0x00000 RW  0x10
  GNU_RELRO      0x000ef0 0x00020ef0 0x00020ef0 0x00110 0x00110 R   0x1

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     .ARM.exidx 
   01     
   02     .interp 
   03     .interp .note.ABI-tag .hash .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .rel.dyn .rel.plt .init .plt .text .fini .rodata .ARM.extab .ARM.exidx .eh_frame 
   04     .init_array .fini_array .jcr .dynamic .got .data .bss 
   05     .dynamic 
   06     .note.ABI-tag 
   07     
   08     .init_array .fini_array .jcr .dynamic
```

I understand why it must segfault. But the real question is: **What inside the C library could possibly be responsible for corrupting the ELF header in that way?**

I want to know that to look for. My suspicion is that somewhere in the lib some compiler intrinsics are used that go wrong. Just a wild guess.

I cross compile for `Linux bha-1CCAE370CE47 3.4.35 #1 Thu Mar 9 11:20:13 HKT 2017 armv5tejl GNU/Linux` with a GCC6.3. The toolchain was build with crosstool-ng. Build system is macOS.

Comment: How do you build your program? How do you link with the library? Please edit your question to include the actual commands used.

Comment: The "corrupt header" looks like a normal shared library while the "good header" is an executable. How did you link that?

Comment: You are so right. I accidentally linked the executable with "-shared" to counter another error I had. My bad :(